# 2 ips on 1 port vs 1 ip on 2 ports

Tags: ip, port

**Background**

I have a PHP-FPM sitting behind an Apache server. As I need to use two different configurations for PHP-FPM, I can configure it to be connected either on:

- 127.0.0.1:9000 and 127.0.0.**2**:9000, or;
- 127.0.0.1:9000 and 127.0.0.1:900**1**

**Question**

I think the above scenario could be applied generally and not just on PHP-FPM setup. So, my question is, is there any difference between a two ips on one port vs one ip on two ports setup? When would you use one over the other?

Comment: Why not just use a unix socket for php-fpm instead of a network socket? That's the recommended configuration now, anyways.

Comment: @EEAA, thanks for the suggestion. The default configuration file still uses the TCP approach. Will look into that soon.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go for multi-IPs. Clients can easily connect to a new IP number (DNS hostname for example). To connect to a new port, you need to pass the client an argument, e.g. :9001. This becomes tricky to manage over time and there are few (any?) good ways to map ports to names humans can easily remember.